# Unity3D - How do you turn off "receive shadows" in a shader made with Shader Graph?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, shader-graph

Unlike default URP shaders, custom Shader Graph shaders dont come with a "receive shadows" checkbox [as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXiAw.png). How can I disable shadow receiving on my shader? Or alternatively, turn off shadow receiving on any material/object that uses my shader

[this is a lit shader that  does have "receive shadows" option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhIgI.png)

Comment: Not really a solution but you can inspect the shader and just copy over the receive shadow logic to your new shader

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Go to your Graph.
2. Below *Properties*, there is a section called *Keywords*.
3. Add a new Keyword, set *Reference* to **_RECEIVE_SHADOWS_OFF**, *Definition* **Shader Feature**, *Scope* **Global** and *Default* **True**.
4. Go to your material, click on **three dots in the right upper corner of the Inspector** and select *Debug*
5. Set *Shader Keywords* to **_RECEIVE_SHADOWS_OFF**

That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off the Receive Shadows within the Graph Settings tab of Graph Inspector panel in your shader graph.

[image]

Comment: This screenshot is for URP, not HDRP.

Answer (score 0):

When you enable the Debug mode of Inspector, you can see the checkbox of Receive Shadows just right bellow the Renderer.

**EDIT:Unfortunately it's not working. and maybe a deprecated interface.**

But the keyword method could be more handy if you'd like to expose it.
You can check the checkbox of the keyword and it turns on and off quickly.
[image]